# How to set different scene size in javafx of two linked fxml file?

Tags: java, javafx

I have created two fxml screen, I'm linking them with a javafx program from there I'm going from one fxml file to another fxml file(By clicking on a button). The screen size of 1st fxml is 1280x768 and 2nd fxml screen size is 820x420. The problem is that whenever i'm executing the 2nd program  screen size is displaying as same as first screen.
Is there any way to change the 2nd screen size.
or any other way to set the screen size same as what i declared.
I know start() method only executes when that javafx file is executing.

Here is my Main.java

```
package application;
import java.io.IOException;
//import com.sun.javafx.css.converters.URLConverter;
//import com.sun.javafx.css.StyleConverterImpl;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
//import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
//  @FXML Button SkipButton;
    @FXML Button exit;
    @FXML TextField Logint1,Logint2;
    @FXML Button LoginB1;
    String s1,s2;

    public void start(Stage st)
    {
        try{
            //For Maximizing button
            st.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);

            //For max and minimum button
            st.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

            //For disabling all button
            //st.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

            st.setTitle("Login Screen");
            Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
            Scene sc=new Scene(root,1280,800);
            st.setScene(sc);
            st.show();      
    }

catch(Exception e) 
    {
    System.out.print("Exception="+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
public void LoginB1(ActionEvent ae) throws IOException
    {
        String s1 = Logint1.getText();
        String s2 = Logint2.getText();
        Stage ps = null;
        if(s1.equals("Admin") && s2.equals("Admin"))
        {
            System.out.println("Equals");
            try{
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
            Parent root=loader.load();
            LoginB1.getScene().setRoot(root);
            throw new IOException(" ");
                }
                catch (IOException ie)
                {

                }
        }
        else
            {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Login is Not Valid");
                alert.setHeaderText("Username or Password not Valid");
                alert.setContentText("Username and Password");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        }
/*
public void SkipBtn(ActionEvent ae) throws IOException
{
    try{

FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FirstSignUp.fxml"));
Parent root=loader.load();
SkipButton.getScene().setRoot(root);
throw new IOException(" ");
    }
    catch (IOException ie)
    {

    }
}
*/
public static void main(String args[])
{
    launch(args);
}
}


Login.fxml which is linked on button LoginB1


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Main">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" style="-fx-background-image: url('E:/home/devil/Desktop/sdadsaffga/a.jpeg');">
         <children>
            <Pane layoutX="-2.0" layoutY="-4.0" prefHeight="501.0" prefWidth="640.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="476.0" fitWidth="640.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@teaser-bg-2.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="txtcpc" layoutX="124.0" text="Central Purchassing System" textFill="#255bcc">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="33.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="Logint1" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="139.0" promptText="Enter Your Username">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                     <effect>
                        <DropShadow />
                     </effect>
                  </TextField>
                  <PasswordField fx:id="Logint2" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="194.0" promptText="Enter Your Password">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                     <effect>
                        <DropShadow />
                     </effect>
                  </PasswordField>

                                            <Button fx:id="LoginB1" layoutX="256.0" layoutY="257.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#LoginB1" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="Login" textFill="#255bccfc">
            <font>
              <Font size="20.0" />
            </font>
                     <effect>
                        <InnerShadow />
                     </effect>


                 </Button>
                  <Label layoutX="118.0" layoutY="199.0" text="Enter Your Password">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="116.0" layoutY="139.0" text="Enter Your Username">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="243.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@CollegeLogo.jpg" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect>
            </Pane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="636.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

2nd Fxml File Home.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Blend?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Home">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="44.0" layoutY="115.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="Home" textFill="#255bcc">
               <font>
                  <Font size="17.0" />
               </font>
               <effect>
                  <Blend />
               </effect>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="createFile" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="112.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createFile" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Add a File" textFill="#255bcc">
               <font>
                  <Font size="17.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="ModifyFile" layoutX="381.0" layoutY="112.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ModifyFile" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="168.0" text="Modify a File" textFill="#255bcc">
               <font>
                  <Font size="17.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="640.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <top>
            <MenuBar prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="640.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New File" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="History" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Modify Existing File" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete Existing File" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help" />
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
         </top>
         <center>
            <Label text="Admin" textFill="#255bcc" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="38.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <Label text="Welcome," textFill="#255bcc">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="32.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </graphic>
            </Label>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Controller file for Home.fxml

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Home extends Application {
@FXML Button createFile,ModifyFile;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
        Scene sc=new Scene(root,1280,800);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public void createFile(ActionEvent ae)// throws IOException
    {
        try{
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("HeadersLayout.fxml"));
        Parent root=loader.load();
        //Scene sc=new Scene(root,1280,800);

        createFile.getScene().setRoot(root);
        throw new IOException("");
        }
        catch(IOException ie)
        {

        }
    }
    public void ModifyFile(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        try{
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Modify.fxml"));
            Parent root=loader.load();
            //Scene sc=new Scene(root,1280,800);

            createFile.getScene().setRoot(root);
            throw new IOException("");
            }
            catch(IOException ie)
            {

            }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code here so we can help you? At least the FXML files in question

Comment: Also the code you execute when you click the button would be quite useful to answer your question!